# What is the fastest and efficient way to check Deep Equal for two java objects?

Tags: java, deepequals

I have got two java objects with `byte[]` field of the *size of the order of millions*. What is the fastest and efficient way to check **Deep Equal** for these java objects?

Sample Entity:

```
@Entity
public class NormalBook
{

  @Id
  private String bookId;

  @Column
  private String title;

  @Column
  private byte[] pdfFile;

  //setters and getters

  }
```

> Note: I am doing it for an ORM tool basically I am checking an object
>   (*which is in managed state*) with an object present in Persistence
>   Context.

Comment: If you do more than one comparison, it probably pays to calculate a checksum/hashcode for each.

Comment: But it's quite a strange thing to do...what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: How did the 'object' end up in a jar file?  Does the jar file contain serialized java objects?  (Be aware that two serialized Java objects that are `equals()` - or even exactly the same instance - may produce a different sequence of bytes each time serialized.)

Comment: @Paul jar file is an example. I have attached a sample entity which may give u  more insight.

Comment: in the case of ORM why it is not enough only to compare the bookId ?

Comment: who said it's enough ?

Comment: Do you really want to be storing the *contents* of the book, via ORM, into - I presume - a RDBMS?  That sounds like a seriously Bad Idea.

Comment: @Paul Its not for RDBMS. It's for NoSQL database

Comment: Still, doing this would seem to mandate loading the entire *contents* of the book into the ORM.  Why do that?  When not just store a relative path to a file on disk?

Comment: @dev In that case you'll save yourself an awful lot of hassle if you also store the checksum of the file in the database.

Comment: True.  But we still don't know why the OP *wants* to check if the *contents* (i.e. bytes) of two books are the same.  Or even if this is merely an artifact of trying to implement equality on a object that is unnecessarily storing the contents, when it doesn't need to (not through the ORM, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `equals()` or have a *helper method (bad option!) and do it in 5 steps :

```
1. Check for *not null*.
2. Check for same *type*.
3. Check for *size of byte[]*.
4. Check for `==` (*reference equality* of byte[]) 
5. Start comparing byte values
```

Comment: If I compare byte value (step 4) , don't you think it will take a lot of time for a large object ?

Comment: @dev Of course the time will be proportional to the object size. What other option do you have to compare other than actually comparing ?

Comment: @dev - Well, if you want to check *value* then you will ahve to do it :) . `Arrays.equals()` will cover steps 3,4 and 5..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the definition of `equals()` on your object's class:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(bs1, bs2)
```

You might also want to check if they are the *same* array (instance) first.  Though this method may well do that anyway.

For example (and making some assumptions about your class that contains the arrays):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof MyObject)) // covers case where obj null, too.
        return false;
    return Arrays.equals(this.bytes, ((MyObject)obj).bytes);
}
```

If there are other fields in your class, your `equals()` should take those into account too.

(There might be a better answer to the question if you could provide more information about what kind of data is stored in the arrays.)

Comment: Ya. `Arrays.equals()` checks references first

Comment: I am saving a jar file of size 20 mb in byte[].

Comment: @dev why are you saving a jar file in a byte[]... what is the purpose?

Comment: Are you trying to check if two jar files are 'equal' (that is, byte-for-byte equivalent)?

Answer (score 0):

if your class have fields like `byte[]` you can use something like:

```
public class MyClass {


    byte[] a;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(a, other.a))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

If you are concern about performance and can assure a **unique `hascode`**(this is important `hascode` need to be `unique`) then you can just compare the hascode.

Comment: Good point.  You should always implement `hashCode()` too, when you override `equals()`.

Comment: How would you assure a unique hashcode? In general, you can't.

Comment: However, hash codes (in Java) *do not* need to be - and usually *are not* - unique.  (They are NOT ids.)  Aside: I once spend two weeks fixing a system written by someone who erraneously believed hash codes are always unique.  `hashCode()` return values should be well-distributed however.  *Effective Java* (Joshua Bloch) provides a good summary of when - and how - to override `hashCode()`.